# docker-compose cant run react without node_modules already existing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Im using docker/docker-compose to get my react (ts) app up and running.
The script im currently using works perfectly, on 1 condition. That I've already did 'npm install' inside the directory, while not in docker.

I would like to be able to clone my project from github, and just do docker-compose up, and that it works than.

Right now i first have to run 'npm install', and than 'docker-compose up' for it to work sadly.

I tried just using `RUN npm install react-scripts -g`, and that kinda works. however i than get a error for typescript, and all other packages.

What I want to be happening is. When I clone my repo, and use `docker-compose up`. That my whole project runs. It also should make a `node_modules` folder in my react folder that I can see in my IDE. This is so that my IDE knows the code in the package and doesn't yell at me the whole time.

I cant figure out how to get this to work, I'm already struggling on this for hours and can't find online how to fix it. Hope anyone can help me :D

My structure looks something like this:

- apps

  - frontend

    - Dockerfile
    - composer.json
    - // All the other react files/folders
- docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.14.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm install

CMD npm start --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000 --disableHostCheck true
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    frontend:
        build:
            context: ./apps/frontend
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./apps/frontend:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        environment:
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
            - API_BASE_URL=host.docker.internal:8080/api
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

The error im getting is:

```
frontend_1  | > spa@0.1.0 start
frontend_1  | > react-scripts start "0.0.0.0" "3000"
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
cyldiscordbot_frontend_1 exited with code 127
```

package.json (idk if you need it, but here it is):

```
{
  "name": "spa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@cylbot/cyldiscordbotlanguage": "^2.0.3",
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "emotion-theming": "^11.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.20",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  }
}
```

I can give out a lot of info about this project, so if more info is required just ask! :D

Comment: Can you please try after removing  "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ], from eslintConfig section in package.json

Comment: @SachinVairagi still getting the same error :(
Btw I am using `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I asked a friend, and he helped me out.
I needed to change my Dockerfile to:

```
FROM node:16.14.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g react-scripts

RUN chown -Rh node:node /usr/src/app

USER node

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run start" ]
```

Comment: Great! thanks for sharing working solution.

Comment: Does it work nice with docker "one process per container" policy?

Comment: To answer my own question: No. It does not play nice, and this trick will cost us extra seconds docker will need to stop container.

Comment: Update: replacing just `npm run start` with direct invokation to react-scripts, and adding init: true option to docker compose allows Docker to manage container with SIGNALs. So no slow container reload.

Answer (score -1):

Your Dockerfile is missing the application code; it only copies the `package.json` file in.  This gives you an incomplete image that you can't just run.  You're missing a line:

```sh
COPY ./ ./
```

I'd put this after the `RUN npm install` line, to make rebuilding the image faster.

Since your image is incomplete, in your current setup you have to inject the code from the host, and that hides the `node_modules` directory that the image builds.  That's why you also have to run `npm install` on the host.  If you `COPY` the application code into the image, you don't need the `volumes:` block.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
    frontend:
        build: ./apps/frontend  # short form with default dockerfile:
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        environment:
            - API_BASE_URL=host.docker.internal:8080/api
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        # no volumes: or polling environment variable
```

Comment: For local dev, code changes will not propagate with this solution.

Comment: For local dev, I wouldn't expect you to try to work inside an isolated Docker container.  Write your code using a host IDE, run its unit tests using a host Node interpreter, and then bring Docker in only when you require its isolation features.  If the code isn't built into the image or if you always ovewrite it with a volume mount, you're only using Docker as an inconvenient way to get a Node interpreter, and there are easier ways to do that.